# Skype/MSN/Yahoo icon for online/offline status

Tags: yahoo, status, skype, msn

I want to show skype/msn/yahoo icons that show the online status in my ASP.NET website. The purpose is that user can click the online icon and can directly chat if he's online on skype/msn/yahoo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Get Skype button](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/tell-a-friend/wizard/)

[Get Yahoo button](http://www.dailytechnologytips.com/2008/09/how-to-add-yahoo-messenger-status.html)

[Get MSN button](https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&ct=1323256997&rver=6.1.6208.0&wp=MBI&wreply=http://settings.messenger.live.com/Applications/CreateHtml.aspx&lc=1033&id=76215)

Answer (score 2):

visit those links for

skype status button 
http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/tell-a-friend/get-a-skype-button/

for yahoo

```
<a href="ymsgr:SendIM?n_nicq">
<img border=0 src="http://opi.yahoo.com/online?u=n_nicq&m=g&t=1"></a>
```

try changing the number  http://opi.yahoo.com/online?u=n_nicq&m=g&t=1 after **t=1** in this line of html and get new buttons for yahoo online /offline status. (note: you can try upto 1-24 let me give you an example so that for no confusion)

```
<a href="ymsgr:SendIM?n_nicq">
<img border=0 src="http://opi.yahoo.com/online?u=n_nicq&m=g&t=1"></a>

<a href="ymsgr:SendIM?n_nicq">
<img border=0 src="http://opi.yahoo.com/online?u=n_nicq&m=g&t=2"></a>

<a href="ymsgr:SendIM?n_nicq">
<img border=0 src="http://opi.yahoo.com/online?u=n_nicq&m=g&t=3"></a>
```

and for msn messenger 
    http://settings.messenger.live.com/Applications/CreateHtml.aspx

enjoy...