# skype status button showing status but if i click on the status it is not connecting to skype

Tags: skype

i implemented skype button in my site it is showing fine with status, but if i click on the button it is not going to call to the user, saying

The address wasn't understood

```
      Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (skype) isn't associated with any program.
```

You might need to install other software to open this address.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413693/skype-msn-yahoo-icon-for-online-offline-status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the widget useful in Firefox, just change link to

```
callto://skype_user_name
```

Answer (score 1):

This button only works for people who installed the skype plugin.

Which is barely anyone. Use a different method instead.

Comment: Actually this is the method to implement skype button in website, i cant fine any other methods, pls help me in this,

Comment: Sorry, I checked after writing that and it seems there is no other method.

Comment: Unfortunately Skype button is not that well supported to be useful for anyone